# Injecting a managedBean in a converter

Tags: jsf, converters, managed-bean

I'm trying to write a converter for my selectonemenu list so the list that i want to display can be retrieved from a managedBean's getter `getDatasetList()` .
My managedBean is viewScoped.

here's the code of the converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "datasetConverter")
public class DatasetConverter implements Converter{

@ManagedProperty(value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB}")
private ProjectCampaignManagementMB campaignManagementMB;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {

     List <DataSet>  datasetList=campaignManagementMB.getDatasetList();

     DataSet dataSet;
     String dataSetName;
     if (datasetList!=null){
            for(int i=0 ;i<datasetList.size();i++)
            {   
                dataSet=datasetList.get(i);
                dataSetName=dataSet.getName();

            if  (dataSetName.equals(value))
                return dataSet;
            System.out.println("getasobject dataset"+dataSet.getName());
            }
     }
            return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {

 if (value==null) return ""; 
    System.out.println("getastring dataset"+((DataSet) value).getName());
 return ((DataSet) value).getName();
}
```

But i'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException on this line

```
  List <DataSet>  datasetList=campaignManagementMB.getDatasetList();
```

So the injected managedBean is Null,

i tried something that has no sense but it works ,but i want something correct .
i used this

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB}")
private ProjectCampaignManagementMB campaignManagementMB =
    new ProjectCampaignManagementMB();
```

instead of

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB}")
private ProjectCampaignManagementMB campaignManagementMB
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why would you want to inject the managed bean in your converter? It would be better to show your functional requirement because this can be a design problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to use managed properties inside your convertor make your convertor a managed bean, like this

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DatasetConverter implements Converter{
```

Than to use it as convertor in your xhtml page just use binding

like this

```
<h:inputText converter="#{datasetConverter}"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem some time ago and I remember that @Inject did not work for me with the converter. What helped me was directly looking up the bean with its JNDI name. Something along this lines:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();  
BeanClass bean = context.lookup("yours bean jndi");
```

If you are using JBoss you can see the beans JNDI on the server startup.