# Expression Error: Named Object: ch.foo.EnitityConverter@f163464 not found

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

After having an instance of a `Converter` within a Managed Bean according to same issue as described in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) questions listed below, I am getting an exception that the object was not found.

```
Expression Error: Named Object: ch.foo.EnitityConverter@f163464 not found
```

Stackoverflow questions:

- [ManagedProperty not injected in @FacesConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135942/managedproperty-not-injected-in-facesconverter)
- [Injecting a managedBean in a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101081/injecting-a-managedbean-in-a-converter)

My xhtml code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedEmployees}">
  <f:converter converterId="#{bean.entityConverter}" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allEmployees}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.name}" />    
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `converterId` attribute expects the converter ID (the converter name). Any EL expression value is evaluated as a `String`. You're basically passing the `toString()` result of your converter instance to it, which is `ch.foo.EnitityConverter@f163464`. This converter ID is in turn not recognized as any of the registered converters. However .. You didn't want to pass the converter ID, but instead just reference a whole converter instance.

The `converterId` attribute is the wrong attribute whenever you want to reference a whole concrete instance instead. Use the `binding` attribute instead, or the input component's `converter` attribute.

Thus, so

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedEmployees}">
  <f:converter binding="#{bean.entityConverter}" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allEmployees}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.name}" />    
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

or

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedEmployees}" converter="#{bean.entityConverter}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allEmployees}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.name}" />    
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is missing `converter` name. Your name may be like `entityConverter`. Default will be calss name. Use as below;

```
   <f:converter converterId="#{entityConverter}" />
```

Comment: I do not use `faces-config.xml` to name a converter. I'm referencing an converter instance in a managed bean. See linked stackoverflow questions. However, thank you for your answer. ;)

Comment: Even you use annotation, there is a name for the converter.

Comment: You pass all the converter itself as its ID here. I don't think it's correct.